# osx openshift MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume with: exit status 1

Tags: macos, openshift

I use the `OpenShift` client on macOS to get an `OpenShift` cluster up and running. I can login on both commandline and web console. But when I try to install an application, e.g. my own simple spring-boot-application or the `openshift/jenkins` template, the deployment process stuck and I get a couple of errors:

> Failed Sync: Error syncing pod
>
> Failed mount: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/972d63f8-bc0e-11e7-b3e2-025000000001-deployer-token-n8bdv" (spec.Name: "deployer-token-n8bdv") pod "972d63f8-bc0e-11e7-b3e2-025000000001" (UID: "972d63f8-bc0e-11e7-b3e2-025000000001") with: exit status 1
>
> Failed mount: Unable to mount volumes for pod "jenkins-1-deploy_myproject(972d63f8-bc0e-11e7-b3e2-025000000001)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "myproject"/"jenkins-1-deploy". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[deployer-token-n8bdv]

Any hints? What does the exit status 1 mean? Or can someone point me to the source code where I can lookup MountVolume.SetUp method?

```
$ oc version
oc v3.6.0+c4dd4cf 
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth

Server https://127.0.0.1:8443
openshift v3.6.0+c4dd4cf
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
```

Comment: You can’t install OpenShift directly to MacOS X. Do you mean you are running Minishift or oc cluster up on OpenShift?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use `oc cluster up`. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: What version of oc?

Comment: oc v3.6.0+c4dd4cf (question updated with version information)

Comment: Finally, I installed minishift and everything works as expected.